# IBM Cloud Private CE update to EE

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

If I start up with IBM Cloud Private CE, install a few things and then later want to upgrade to EE.  Is there a migration path from the CE installation to EE, or do I have to essentially have to start all over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @bryanw, this is not supported.